# How to visualize a step-by-step process about Complete-Linkage Clustering in a C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, statistics, hierarchical-clustering

How to make or visualize a step-by-step process about Complete-Linkage Clustering in a C++ program? Is there some sort of special library or equation? [Course Material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering#First_step)

I already know how to input the data in matrix array and find the minimum value.

```
int rows,column;
int minimum, locx, locy;
cout<<"Input column    : ";cin>>column;
cout<<"Input rows      : ";cin>>rows;

float matrix[rows][column];
    for(int i=0;i<=rows;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            cout<<"Input the data in row "<<i<<" column "<<j<<" :";cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

cout<<"TABLE :"<<endl<<endl;
for(int k=0;k<=rows;k++){
    for(int m=1;m<=k;m++){
        cout<<"   | "<<matrix[k][m]<<"  |";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

for(int n=0;n<=rows;n++) {
    for(int p=1;p<=n;p++){
        if (matrix[n][p] < minimum)  {
            minimum = matrix[n][p];
            locx = p;
            locy = n;
            }
    }
}
cout << "Minimum value is " << minimum << " on row no. " << locy << " and column no. " << locx << endl;
```

The next process (pictured sample) is hard and confusing.
[image: Matrix Update]

Anybody know how to identified the rows and columns? And how to update the matrix using the new one, repeat the process, until the last matrix (2x2)?
[Course Material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering#First_step)

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of datastructure for the array is a bit unfortunate, but you can work in-place by copying rows up and columns to the left.

```
std::vector<std::string> labels; // Fill this with {"a","b",...}

int n = rows;
while (n > 1) {
  int min1, min2;

  // TODO: insert loop to get row and column of smallest element 
  // We assume min1 < min2

  // Overwrite row min1 and column min1 with the new distance.
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int new_value = std::max(matrix[i][min1], matrix[i][min2]);
    matrix[i][min1] = matrix[min1][i] = new_value;
  }

  // Record that we joined min1 and min2
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "(" << labels[min1] << ", " << labels[min2] << ")";
  labels[min1] = oss.str();
  labels.erase(labels.begin()+min2);

  // We now have D_n+1, with a bogus column at min2.
  // We get rid of it by moving all columns > min2 to the left,
  // and same for all rows > min2
  for (int i = min2; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = matrix[i+1][j];
      matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i+1];
    }
  }

  n--;
}
```